# tk window crashes when using after method

Tags: python, tkinter, crash

I am trying to make a madlibs app so I am making a GUI for `input()` in Python but when I try to, the function doesn't run and the GUI does not even show up! Could someone please help me?
Here is my code:

```py
import tkinter as tk

app=tk.Tk()
d=None
def check():
    if d != None:
      return
    else:
      app.after(10, check)



app.title("Vacation MadLibs")
def help():
  helpWindow = tk.Toplevel(app) 
  tk.Label(helpWindow, text="How to play:\nThis game is called MadLibs!\nYou will be asked a series of questions that you will have\nto answer. After you are done answering the questions we\nwill show you a story that you created!").pack()
tk.Button(app,text="How to play",command= help).pack()
label=tk.Label(app,text="")


textbox=tk.Text(app, height= 1, width= 6 )

def enter():
  global d
  d = textbox.get("1.0","end")

button=tk.Button(app,command= enter)



def getInput(text):
  
  label.pack()
  textbox.pack()
  button.pack()
  check()
  label["text"]=text
  

answer1= getInput("Name an emotion....   ")
answer2= getInput("Name a place....   ")
answer3= getInput("Name a person....    ")
answer4= getInput("Name a vehicle....   ")
answer5= getInput("Name a number....    ")
answer6= getInput("Name another number....    ")
answer7= getInput("Name a verb....    ")
answer8= getInput('Name an adjective....    ')
answer9= getInput("Name an animal...    ")
answer10= getInput("Name another adjective....   ")
answer11= getInput("Name a food...    ")
answer12= getInput("Name an emotion...   ")
answer13= getInput("Name a famous person....     ")
answer14= getInput("Name an adjective....   ")

print("This is your story...")
print("Im so " + answer1)
print("Today we are going on a vacation to " + answer2)
print("Im going with " + answer3)
print("and we will travel there by " + answer4)
print ("The journey will take " + answer5 )
print ("hours and we will stay there for " + answer6)
print("days. After we arrived we decided to  " + answer7)
print("Then we saw a " + answer8)
print(answer9)
print("We were starving so we decided to eat a " + answer10)
print(answer11)
print("We were so " + answer12)
print("Because we met " + answer13)
print("Overall the vacation was really " + answer14 )
```

I read on the internet that if I use the after method my app will not crash but it crashes.

Comment: Calling `input()` is going to freeze the GUI whether you call it with `after` or not. That's what it's designed to do - to pause the program until you've input something. Also, nowhere in the posted code do you call `input`.

Comment: @BryanOakley I am not using input() I am trying to make a GUI version of it

Comment: The code you posted never defines anything named `input` and never calls `getInput`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: ok, I will edit the post. Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not at all how to get input from a user. The very nature of GUI development means the program is always running in a loop waiting for events, so you don't need to create your own loops.

Instead, you can use tkinter's `wait_variable` method to wait until a variable is set. You can set that variable when the user clicks a button or they press the return key.  `wait_variable` is similar to `mainloop` except that it automatically returns as soon as the variable is set. Like `mainloop`, however, it will listen for and respond to events.

It might look something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk

def getInput(prompt):
    label.configure(text=prompt)
    textbox.delete("1.0", "end")

    label.pack()
    textbox.pack()
    button.pack()

    textbox.wait_variable(var)
    return var.get()

def enter(event=None):
    var.set(textbox.get("1.0", "end-1c"))

app=tk.Tk()
app.title("Vacation MadLibs")

var = tk.StringVar()
label=tk.Label(app,text="")
textbox=tk.Text(app, height= 1, width= 6 )
button=tk.Button(app,command= enter)

textbox.bind("<Return>", enter)

answer1= getInput("Name an emotion....   ")
answer2= getInput("Name a place....   ")
...
```